# Python : Displaying a sorted dictionary by more than one condition

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary, multiple-conditions

What I want my code to do is to sum the parcial grades of each student and return their final grade, ordering them by grade, **and** *if for students with the **same grade***, display the high number student first.

My code:

```
nice={}

try:

    with open('grades.txt') as file:
        data = file.readlines()

except IOError as ioerr:
    print(str(ioerr))


for each_line in data:
    (number, grade) = each_line.split()
    if number not in nice:
        nice[number]=0
    nice[number]+=int(grade)


for i in sorted(nice, key=lambda n: (-nice[n],n)):
    print(i,nice[i])
```

my Input: file: "grades.txt"

```
10885 10
70000 6
70000 10
60000 4
70000 4
60000 4
10885 10
60001 5
60002 8
60003 8
```

my output:

```
10885 20
70000 20
60000 8
60002 8
60003 8
60001 5
```

As you can see, I've already found a way to sum each parcial grade to a final grade and display them by their grades, yet I've not figured out how to implement the other condition, effectively getting this **desired output**:

```
10885 20
70000 20
60003 8
60002 8
60000 8
60001 5
```

Since students 60000,60002,60003 have the **same grade**, they should be displayed as above, for 60003>60002>60000.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

its often helpful to try and think of it just slightly different (ie a condition inverted)

```
sorted(nice.items(), key=lambda itm: map(int,itm[::-1]),reverse=True)
```

or in python 3

```
sorted(nice.items(), key=lambda v: (int(v[1]),int(v[0])),reverse=True)
```

or

```
sorted(nice.items(), key=lambda itm: list(map(int,itm[::-1])),reverse=True)
```

should work for python2 or 3

**python3.4.3**

```
>>> nice
{'60000': '8', '60001': '5', '70000': '20', '60003': '8', '10885': '20', '60002': '8'}
>>> sorted(nice.items(), key=lambda itm: list(map(int,itm[::-1])),reverse=True)
[('70000', '20'), ('10885', '20'), ('60003', '8'), ('60002', '8'), ('60000', '8'), ('60001', '5')]
```

Comment: 10885 20
60000 8
60003 8
60001 5
60002 8
70000 20 , I'm getting this output with your code sir. (Python 3)

Comment: KeyError: ('10885', 20) , do note I didn't cast the student number to an int, therefore it is considered a string if I'm not mistaken

Comment: hmmm I think you must be doing something outside of this code